# Difference between cxfrs:server and jaxrs:server

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi, cxfrs

I would like to know the difference between cxfrs and jaxrs. Also the difference between using cxfrs:server and jaxrs:server in my blueprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cxfrs Just for the  define the endpoint information about camel-cxfrs, jaxrs is using CXF directly to consumer or provide JAXRS service.